# Java hashmap Object's quantity

Tags: java, hashmap

User has capability to buy items.

I use two different hashmaps.

```
static LinkedHashMap<String, Item> haveItems = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

For storing which items the user already has and to search / buy them by using item's name.

```
static LinkedHashMap<Item, Integer> itemsQuantity = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

For storing quantity of those items.

Can I simplify it and have just one map and how?
I can not put parameter quantity into Item, because User and Store may have different quantities of an item. Or maybe there is some another option?

Comment: What are the meaning of the keys and values from both maps and why are these fields `static`?

Comment: Assuming the `Item`s are the same, you can try researching `pair`.

Comment: Perhaps the cleanest approach is to encapsulate the item + quantity into an object (e.g. `StockEntry`), and use the lookup map to point to instances of that

Comment: It may not be the best option, but you can use MutiValueMap too. Although I would use the encapsulation as @robinsax suggested.